# Creating a zero dollar or 0% coupon code in Magento

Tags: magento

I'm spinning my wheels trying to figure out a way to create a way for a 0% or zero dollar coupon code. Currently when a user enters the coupon I made with those settings it accepts the code but does not display the 0.00 as a line item in the shopping cart. Bumping it up to 0.01 works though.

Any thoughts are appreciated.

Comment: why on earth would you want to do this? could you explain, maybe there is a better way?

Comment: The reason is because the client is starting a fundraiser drive where folks will apply a discount code during a purchase and we will give the school back 20% after we tally up all the purchases made with that code.

Answer (score 0):

In case you don't find any success with Discount code feature of Magento then you can try using text type custom option for product with zero price, which will save you discount code with order. And then you can perform whatever operation you want with information in backend.